# Habilitar input dependiente de un chekbox

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

El modal muestra datos que se recuperan mediante una consulta y lo estoy llenando con un ciclo for.

Con varias pruebas que hice logre obtener true o false que son el valor del checkbox pero lo que no cambia es el estado de los input a enable o disable segun el caso ese es mi principal problema.

En esta funcion se centra mi problema con las pruebas que hice no logro resolver el prob.
    enableDisable(option)

[image: Imagen que muestra el modal]

```
<div id="modalPay" class="modal fade modal-child" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form  action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
                                <h4><strong>Nombre de cliente:</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9" id="clientName">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">Fecha compra</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Monto total</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">A cuenta</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Saldo</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Habilitar pago</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Monto a pagar</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Detalles</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="myFormPay">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSavePay" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->



    <script>    
                $('#modalPay').modal('show');
                $('#modalPay').find('.modal-title').text('Realizar pago');
                $('#myFormPay').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>pagov/addPay');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>pagov/makePay',
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        var html = '';
                        var html1 = ''; 
                        html1 += '<h4><strong>'+data[0].ven_cliente+'</strong></h4>';
                                $('#clientName').html(html1);
                        var i;
                        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                            html += '<tr>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>'+data[i].ven_fecha+'</strong></td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>'+data[i].ven_total+'</strong></td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>'+data[i].pv_monto+'</strong></td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>'+(data[i].ven_total - data[i].pv_monto)+'</strong></td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center">'+
                                            '<input type="checkbox" id="checkedItem'+i+'" onchange="enableDisable(this.id)">'+
                                            '</td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" align="center">'+
                                            '<input id="payItem'+i+'" type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="100000"  style="width:85px" maxlength="6" disabled="disabled">'+
                                            '</td>'+
                                            '<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" align="center">'+
                                               '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-list vent-detail" data="' + data[i].ven_id + '"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Detalle de venta"/>' +
                                               '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt item-pay" data="' + data[i].ven_id + '"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Historial de pagos"/>' +
                                            '</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' ;
                                    }
                                $('#myFormPay').html(html);
                                }
                            });
                        });
function enableDisable(option){
          //en esta  
           var chk = document.getElementById(option).value;
           //var chk  = option.
           if(chk === 'on'){
            $('#payItem0').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
           alert(chk);
            }
        }     
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola @M.Antonio, no modifiques el código original de la pregunta con la respuesta ya que si no los futuros lectores no podrán ver cual era el error. Te revoco tu último cambio al estado anterior para que quede claro cual es el problema y la solución al problema.

Comment: entendido... pero era para poder mostrar lo q reemplace ya q crei q no me estaba dejando entender...

Comment: En esos casos es mucho mejor añadir un pequeño apunte debajo del script original para no perder el hilo de la pregunta con el código que has modificado, en este caso, la función por ejemplo. Ahora queda bien así, pero así lo tienes en cuenta para la próxima :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error está en que tienes que comprobar el estado del checkbox mediante la propiedad `checked` ya que esta te devolverá `true` o `false` dependiendo si el checkbox está activo o no. El checkbox, al no tener valor, siempre te devolverá el valor por defecto, que en este caso es "on" por lo que siempre te entrará en la condición.

Además, en vez de pasarle el id al llamar a la función le podrías pasar solamente la palabra reservada `this` que hará referencia al checkbox que estés pulsando, no teniendo que volver a obtener el mismo checkbox con la propiedad `getElementById`.

Como quieres que se habilite también el elemento correspondiente a su `checkbox`, entonces le podrías pasar como parámetro el índice de dicho `checkbox` para después aplicarle el estilo correspondiente a cada `input` según el índice que tenga.

```
onchange="enableDisable(this," + i + ")"
```

Por último, tal y como ha comentado @CesarRomero, no sería necesario el `if` ya que vas a habilitar o deshabilitar tu `input` en función del valor del `checkbox`.

Tendrías que modificar un poco tu función:

```
function enableDisable(option,i){
    var chk = option.checked;

    $('#payItem' + i).prop('disabled',!chk);
}
```

Comment: Como sugerencia creo que no seria necesario el `if`; ya que la función va a habilitar/deshabilitar el input correspondiente a su artículo.

Comment: @CesarRomero Tienes razón, en este caso no tiene ninguna utilidad. De hecho, no establecería el disabled en caso de que el checkbox estuviera desmarcado. Muchas gracias por el apunte!

Comment: Entiendo todo de su ayuda pero olvide mencionar que al habilitar el `id="checkedItem'+i+'"` se cambie el de estado el `id="payItem'+i+'"` el id cambia de nombre dependiendo a la cantidad de elementos que tenga la consulta, en esa parte estoy un poco perdido ya que no logre cambiar el estado del input ni del primer elemento.

Comment: @M.Antonio He editado un poco la respuesta con lo que propones. De esta manera, lo haría de forma dinámica y establecería la propiedad `disabled` para el elemento correspondiente a cada `checkbox`.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero esta mucho mejor esa parte pero no cambia el valor del input por nada del mundo con este fragmento de codigo `$('#payItem' + i).attr('disabled',!chk);`,  ni con otro que probe

Comment: @M.Antonio ¿Podrías indicarme como lo tienes actualmente?

Comment: Tal como la respuesta ni mas ni menos, reemplace todo hice la depuracion y en teoria cambia el estado del input, pero en el modal sigue en disabled

Comment: @M.Antonio He cambiado la función a `prop` en vez de `attr`. En principio te debería de funcionar.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero funciono muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Es porque al momento de cargar la tabla no le estas avisado cuando debe de estar en checked, intenta con esto en la linea de la tabla js

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="checkedItem'+i+' onchange="enableDisable(this.id)"  ' + data[i].HabiliarPago ? "checked" : "" +'>'+
```

Al final del checbox agregué una validación ternaria, con la cual agrega la propiedad de checked desde tu data.

Comment: Con varias pruebas que hice logre obtener true o false que son el valor del checkbox pero lo que no cambia es el estado de los input a enable o disable segun el caso ese es mi principal problema.

Comment: tenía un error en la propiedad checked, intentalo de nuevo